# How does mmap interract with Go's garbage collector?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, mmap

Go has a garbage collector for slices that only frees the slice when all references to it are dead. It also has an [Mmap function](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mmap) that returns a `[]byte` that can be explicitly freed with `Munmap()`. So how does this work with Go's garbage collector.

What happens if I do this?

```
m := syscall.Mmap(...)
m2 = m[10:100]
syscall.Munmap(m)
a = m2[0]
```

Comment: The GC has no knowledge of manually allocated memory. I'm not sure what you'r expecting from your example.

Comment: I'm expecting it to not behave correctly because the memory pointed to by `m` (and hence `m2`) is freed by `Munmap()`.

Comment: Yes, this will segfault. Did you try running an example? It doesn't have anything to do with garbage collection, it's simply accessing memory that's been freed.

Answer (score 0):

`mmap` memory acts like any other process memory that came from C, or outside of Go.  Go's garbage collector will not scan it.

Go's runtime knows where all its own heap arenas are, so it can tell just based on the address that the `mmap` memory is not part of the go heap.

Go structures can point into it, but if you have pointers back from mapped memory into the go heap, the garbage collector will not see them.   If you unmap the memory and keep a dangling pointer into it and try to use it, your program will crash.

If you take a program that uses big, long lived `[]byte` buffers allocated in the go heap, and replace them with slices that point into mapped memory, you may actually notice that while your memory footprint got smaller, your CPU usage went up.    This is because, by default go's garbage collector is [tuned to free up about half the heap on each GC cycle](https://tip.golang.org/doc/gc-guide).   So by moving your buffers out of the Go heap, you're making the total size of the heap smaller, and therefore the rate of GC cycles per bytes allocated goes up.   In effect, by using big, long lived buffers in the first place you have tuned the GC to favor CPU throughput over memory footprint.   If the buffers are converted into `mmap` regions they become invisible to the GC, and so it see's a smaller heap, and triggers more GC cycles.